# Angular cdk drag and drop into Material dialog

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material, lifecycle, angular-cdk

I am implementing a Drag and Drop using Angular cdk and am getting stuck trying to drag the element into a Dialog which is a child container of the container that contains the cdkDropListGroup. To demonstrate the hierarchy graphically:

[image]

All the white boxes are components. The final goal is to be able to drag and drop elements between all Child components of WorkbenchComponent, including the ones that are generated programmatically.

Obviously since they are not part of the "template tree" at compile time however, the WorkbenchComponent cdkDropListGroup does not include the dialogs.

Now I am struggling to find any way how to make the drag and drop into the SubwindowComponents work (using Material).

HTML5 drag and drop as well as primeng drag and drop does not work unfortunately, due to security restrictions with certain browsers in the deployment context.

Edit: Maybe something along the lines of ComponentFactoryResolver or ViewContainerRef could work?

Comment: I think the root cause of the issue is where the `MatDialog` is inserted in the DOM - i.e. in a `cdk-overlay-container` in the body of the document. This means that it won't be a part of your `cdkDropListGroup` in the DOM structure. As an experiment, try providing custom `OverlayContainer` in your component that will the insert the overlay and it's contents into your `WorkbenchComponent` - I think it should then work correctly. It will probably cause other issues, but this should give you the idea of what is causing the issue.

Comment: Let me try (and learn how) to do that, and I'll come back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing more information about (what I believe to be) the approach suggested by @TotallyNewb. (And what I would choose as the accepted answer)

The solution is rather simple. In the component that generates the materials DialogComponent instances (here: the SidebarSubwindowComponent), we need to add the ViewContainerRef to the MatDialogConfig object that is passed to the open method of the dialog. This ViewContainerRef can be passed on to all grandchildren. In code:

1. Parent component (member of cdkDropListGroup)

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor (private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  openDialog() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.viewContainerRef = this.viewContainerRef;

    let childDialogComponent = ChildDialogComponent;

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(childDialogComponent , dialogConfig);
    
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe();
  }
}
```

2. Child Component (with Dialog)

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

export class SubwindowTableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor (private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  showGrandChild() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.viewContainerRef = this.viewContainerRef;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(GrandChildDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
    // and so on and so forth
  }
}
```